# Accessing and modifying automatic variables on another thread's stack

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to pass some data around threads but want to refrain from using global variables if I can manage it. The way I wrote my thread routine has the user passing in a separate function for each "phase" of a thread's life cycle: For instance this would be a typical usage of spawning a thread:

```
void init_thread(void *arg) {
  graphics_init(); 
}
void process_msg_thread(message *msg, void *arg) {
  if (msg->ID == MESSAGE_DRAW) {
    graphics_draw();
  }
}
void cleanup_thread(void *arg) {
  graphics_cleanup();
}

int main () {
  threadCreator factory;
  factory.createThread(init_thread, 0, process_msg_thread, 0, cleanup_thread, 0);
  // even indexed arguments are the args to be passed into their respective functions
  // this is why each of those functions must have a fixed function signature is so they can be passed in this way to the factory
}

// Behind the scenes: in the newly spawned thread, the first argument given to 
// createThread() is called, then a message pumping loop which will call the third 
// argument is entered. Upon receiving a special exit message via another function 
// of threadCreator, the fifth argument is called.
```

The most straightforward way to do it is using globals. I'd like to avoid doing that though because it is bad programming practice because it generates clutter.

A certain problem arises when I try to refine my example slightly:

```
void init_thread(void *arg) {
  GLuint tex_handle[50]; // suppose I've got 50 textures to deal with.
  graphics_init(&tex_handle); // fill up the array with them during graphics init which loads my textures
}
void process_msg_thread(message *msg, void *arg) {
  if (msg->ID == MESSAGE_DRAW) { // this message indicates which texture my thread was told to draw
    graphics_draw_this_texture(tex_handle[msg->texturehandleindex]); // send back the handle so it knows what to draw
  }
}
void cleanup_thread(void *arg) {
  graphics_cleanup();
}
```

I am greatly simplifying the interaction with the graphics system here but you get the point. In this example code tex_handle is an automatic variable, and all its values are lost when `init_thread` completes, so will not be available when `process_msg_thread` needs to reference it.

I can fix this by using globals but that means I can't have (for instance) two of these threads simultaneously since they would trample on each other's texture handle list since they use the same one.

I can use thread-local globals but is that a good idea?

I came up with one last idea. I can allocate storage on the heap in my parent thread, and send a pointer to in to the children to mess with. So I can just free it when parent thread leaves away since I intend for it to clean up its children threads before it exits anyway. So, something like this:

```
void init_thread(void *arg) {
  GLuint *tex_handle = (GLuint*)arg; // my storage space passed as arg
  graphics_init(tex_handle); 
}
void process_msg_thread(message *msg, void *arg) {
  GLuint *tex_handle = (GLuint*)arg; // same thing here
  if (msg->ID == MESSAGE_DRAW) { 
    graphics_draw_this_texture(tex_handle[msg->texturehandleindex]); 
  }
}
int main () {
  threadCreator factory;
  GLuint *tex_handle = new GLuint[50]; 
  factory.createThread(init_thread, tex_handle, process_msg_thread, tex_handle, cleanup_thread, 0);
  // do stuff, wait etc
  ...
  delete[] tex_handle;
}
```

This looks more or less safe because my values go on the heap, my main thread allocates it then lets children mess with it as they wish. The children can use the storage freely since the pointer was given to all the functions that need access.

So this got me thinking why not just have it be an automatic variable:

```
int main () {
  threadCreator factory;
  GLuint tex_handle[50]; 
  factory.createThread(init_thread, &tex_handle, process_msg_thread, &tex_handle, cleanup_thread, 0);
  // do stuff, wait etc
  ...
} // tex_handle automatically cleaned up at this point
```

This means children thread directly access parent's stack. I wonder if this is kosher. 
I found this on the internets: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/inspectorxe/en-us/win/ug_docs/olh/common/Problem_Type__Potential_Privacy_Infringement.htm

it seems Intel Inspector XE detects this behavior. So maybe I shouldn't do it? Is it just simply a warning of potential privacy infringement as suggested by the the URL or are there other potential issues that may arise that I am not aware of?

P.S. After thinking through all this I realize that maybe this architecture of splitting a thread into a bunch of functions that get called independently wasn't such a great idea. My intention was to remove the complexity of requiring coding up a message handling loop for each thread that gets spawned. I had anticipated possible problems, and if I had a generalized thread  implementation that always checked for messages (like my custom one that specifies the thread is to be terminated) then I could guarantee that some future user could not accidentally forget to check for that condition in each and every message loop of theirs.

The problem with my solution to that is that those individual functions are now separate and cannot communicate with each other. They may do so only via globals and thread local globals. I guess thread local globals may be my best option.

P.P.S. This got me thinking about RAII and how the concept of the thread at least as I have ended up representing it has a certain similarity with that of a resource. Maybe I could build an object that represents a thread more naturally than traditional ways... somehow. I think I will go sleep on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your thread functions into a class. Then they can communicate using instance variables. This requires your thread factory to be changed, but is the cleanest way to solve your problem.

Your idea of using automatic variables will work too as long as you can guarantee that the function whose stack frame contains the data will never return before your child threads exit. This is not really easy to achieve, even after `main()` returns child threads can still run.